# Selenium Python get_element by ID failing

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Can someone help me understand why my code fails to find the element by ID. Code below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://app.waitwhile.com/checkin/lltest3/user')
element = driver.find_element_by_id("guestPhone")
```

Inspecting element shows the ID clearly.

```
<input type="tel" name="guestPhone" id="guestPhone" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-phone-validator ng-invalid-required ng-touched" ng-model="form.model" ng-model-options="{ 'updateOn': 'default blur', 'debounce': { 'default': 350, 'blur': 0 } }" uib-typeahead="guest.phone for guest in form.onChange({value:$viewValue})" typeahead-min-length="6" typeahead-on-select="form.onSelect({guest:$item})" typeahead-select-on-exact="true" uib-tooltip="Please enter valid number. Include country code for non-US numbers" tooltip-trigger="'none'" tooltip-is-open="(form.guestForm.$submitted || form.guestForm.guestPhone.$touched) &amp;&amp; form.guestForm.guestPhone.$invalid" tooltip-placement="bottom" ng-required="::form.required" phone-validator="US" placeholder="Mobile phone" title="Please enter a valid phone number" autocomplete="nope" next-on-enter="" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="typeahead-47-2884" required="required" style="">
```

P.S. I've also tried XPath and name as well. Still no luck.

Comment: Do you have any idea to go for Ruby? There is wrapper WATIR which sits on Ruby Selenium Binding, If you use that, this kind of problem and many other problem would not even come to your notification because everything which are required before carry out an action is well taken care of in WATIR.

Comment: No - I particularly need it in the python language @Rajagopalan

Comment: Okay no problem. The way that's given in the accepted answer is fine but you need to take care of every element individually this way if it's loading time is delayed and also sometime you would be facing stale element error, all these errors you need to take care from your program and I believe that's increasing our effort and running into risk of getting failure is high because unexpected error might show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for the element to become visible on the page. You can tell this is loaded in dynamically because if you right-click on the page in chrome and view source you'll see there's no guestPhone element. It gets loaded in with javascript

Here's an example from http://isaacviel.name/make-web-driver-wait-element-become-visiable/:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading")
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement"))
    )
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with **web driver wait** :

**Code** :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'D:/Automation/chromedriver.exe')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://app.waitwhile.com/checkin/lltest3/user")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)  

element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'guestPhone')))
element.send_keys('006867987')
```